# Python def replace

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

What would the body be if I was to make a function that is designed to modify lst so that its element at pos is replaced with item. Without built-in functions

For example:

```
>>> def replace(lst, pos, item): 
...     mylist = [1,2,3] 
...
>>> replace(mylist, 2, 'a') 
>>> mylist 
[1, 2, 'a']
```

I'm just curious

Comment: Does `lst[pos]=item` count as a built-in function?

Comment: @tobias nope that's not a built in

Comment: @thefourtheye I believe no

Comment: Good. So, are there any more questions?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be passing `mylist` into the method before you initialize `mylist`. Then you create a `mylist` in your method, completely ignoring the list that was passed as a parameter. Instead you should do it as follows:

```
def replace(lst, pos, item): 
    lst[pos] = item

>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> replace(mylist, 2, 'a') 
>>> mylist
[1, 2, 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

[`operator.setitem`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) is what you're looking for.

```
import operator 
mylist = [1,2,3]
operator.setitem(mylist, 2, 'a')
mylist
=> [1, 2, 'a']
```

As @tobias_k noted, this is equivalent to (the more explicit, more readable, more pythonic) plain item-assignment: `mylist[2] = 'a'`